# Mysql insert records that are not in the same table

Tags: php, mysql

Hello good day I have these 4 records as you see below.

```
-----fecha---
2018/03/01 0:05
2018/03/01 0:15
2018/03/01 0:20
--------------
```

They are registered in mysql with their respective id.

what I want to do from the mysql if there is a method or something that shows me the records that do not match

For example, I have several records, these records go in 5 minutes to 5 minutes as seen in the table, what I want to do is that mysql shows me the record that is not there, for example, it is not the

2018/03/01 0:10 and that only shows that

I appreciate your help.

Comment: What is the source of the dates you wish to check?  Also, it appears you are storing your dates as text in MySQL.  This is generally undesirable and you should proper date types instead.

Comment: This is easier to do in PHP than in SQL.

Comment: Loop through the values in order, and if a value is not equal to 5 minutes after the previous one, you know that there's a gap, and you can calculate all the missing times by adding 5 in a loop.

Comment: Guessing this is a appointments thing, so you would have your range in a day, use a select to get the result in the range and then use array_diff to show only your desired dates/times

Comment: I want you to print the record that is not there, use the datetime

Answer (score 0):

You should fix `0:` as it's not a valid hour value.

You can do it like the following using DateTime, but your need to define the start and end values, I'm presuming you're doing that in selecting your "fecha" data.

```
<?php
// query this in a select
$result = [
    '2018/04/12 00:05',
    '2018/04/12 00:15',
    '2018/04/12 00:20', 
];

// define start/end by first and last items in array
$begin = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', min($result));
$end = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y/m/d H:i', max($result));

$interval = new DateInterval('PT5M'); // plus time 5 min
$daterange = new DatePeriod($begin, $interval ,$end);

// build an array to compare it with
foreach ($daterange as $date){
    $range[] = $date->format("Y/m/d H:i");
}

// array diff out the differences
print_r(array_diff($range, $result))
?>
```

https://3v4l.org/faWEY

**Result:**

```
Array
(
    [1] => 2018/04/12 00:10
)
```